Problem registering fluent validation behavior with MediatR with minimal apis
I have an app setup with controllers and a Fluent validation Behavior setup with MediatR, it's working when the request is in an MVC controller but when i try making the same request from a minimal api endpoint, the validation fails to get the request validator from the service collection.
i get this exception:
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Mediator.IPipelineBehavior`2[TestApp.Application.Tokens.Queries.Generate.GenerateTokenQuery,ErrorOr.ErrorOr`1[TestApp.Application.Tokens.Queries.Generate.GenerateTokenResult]]]' from root provider.

I tried changing the lifetime of the pipline and mediator but it still didn't work, so I thought that maybe this is an issue with MediatR itself and I had wanted to try the source generated mediator, so i swapped it out and tried again but it was the same result, so maybe there is a difference between controllers and minimal apis in scope that i don't know about?
